# Custom error formatting

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have implemented my own custom error:

```
function MyError() {
    var temp = Error.apply(this, arguments);
    temp.name = this.name = 'MyError';
    this.stack = temp.stack;
    this.message = temp.message;
}

MyError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: MyError,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});
```

And what I'm missing is to make it display itself on screen as it would when a regular unhanded error occurs, i.e. if we do `throw new Error('Hello!')`, we get output:

```
throw new Error('Hello!');
^

Error: Hello!
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJS\tests\test1.js:28:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Now I want the same nicely formatted output when I'm doing this:

```
try {
    throw new MyError("Ops!");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
{ [MyError: Ops!]
  name: 'MyError',
  stack: 'MyError: Ops!\n    at MyError.Error (native)\n    at new MyError (D:\\NodeJS\\tests\\test1.js:2:22)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\\NodeJS\\tests\\test1.js:22:11)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)\n    at O
bject.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)\n    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)\n    at startup (node.js:138:18)\n
at node.js:974:3',
  message: 'Ops!' }
```

What else needs to be done to make `console.log(e)` output the same nicely formatted presentation for `MyError` automatically, without having to use explicit `e.stack` reference?

**UPDATE:** At first I saw some recommendations regarding method `toJSON` to be implemented, which I did, but it didn't quite work. I assume there must be an overridable method that `console.log` uses in order to format an error object, but what is it then?

Comment: Well, I assume it's just the error being logged different when you just throw it, instead of logging the error object. So if you just threw it then maybe you'd get the same format. Anyway, looking at your properties, you could always make your own log function that matches that format.

Comment: @MinusFour, ...my own `log` function? Would you please clarify? How will it make `console.log(e)` output the error properly formatted?

Comment: but, errors do show up nicely by default in the console... with callstack and everything...

Comment: @Sebas only when left unhandled. When you handle them and use `console.log`, they come up ugly.

Comment: @vitaly-t why don't you use `console.error()` instead?

Comment: @Sebas in this case it makes no difference, the output is exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `toJSON` method (or, `toString` as is frequently assumed), you should override `inspect`, which is used when trying to `console.log` an object in V8.

For example:

```
MyError.prototype.inspect = function () {
    return this.stack;
};
```

should probably do the trick.

Comment: This is precisely the answer I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
  throw new MyError("Ops!");
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.stack);
}
```

If you execute this code in the console of your browser it will display like this:

```
MyError: Ops!
  at MyError.Error (native)
  at new MyError (<anonymous>:3:22)
  at <anonymous>:18:11
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
  at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)
```

If I understand correctly what you want is to print the stack of your error?

Comment: The output is good, yes, but I was hoping there was a way to make such output automatically, without the explicit reference to `e.stack`. Is there no way to extend `MyError` to do that? The problem is, `e` may refer to other errors, including ones not necessarily having any `stack` at all.

Comment: I have updated the bottom section of my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function to handle **uncaughtException** Errors so that the server does not stops on unhandled errors.

**Function**

```
function errorHandler (){
  process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err); // Displays the Error;
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message); // Displays the Date and Error Message.
    console.error(err.stack);  // Stack in Which the error occurred.
  });
}
```

**Output**

```
ISODate("2015-07-28T04:56:20.000Z") uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'asset' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'asset' of undefined\n
 at /Path/file.js:31:31\n
 at /path/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:436:11\n    
 at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
```

Hope This Helps.

Comment: To abbreviate my question: how to make `console.log` display my custom error well-formatted?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very recommended, but you could always hook the `console.log` handler:

```
var oldhandler = console.log;
console.log = function () {
    if (typeof(arguments[0].stack) != "undefined" && arguments[0] instanceof(Error) && typeof(arguments[0].stack) != "undefined") {
        oldhandler.apply(console,[arguments[0].stack]);
    } else {
        oldhandler.apply(console,arguments);
    }                                                                                                                              
}

try {
    throw new Error("qweqew");
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xagpf5ff/